# Commercialising an electronic project - Li-ion pouch cells or coin cells?

Tags: lithium-ion, coin-cell

I'm looking to move past the prototype stage and bring a small, low voltage, wireless electronic project to market. (it's a musical instrument)

The prototype incorporated a Li-ion pouch cell and USB charging circuitry, but I think in a commercial product, this would come with greater liability/regulatory risk.

Am I correct in this assumption; that using Li-ion pouch would be "opening a can of worms" (and possibly make the entire commercialisation endeavour unfeasible)?

If so, would coin cells be a better route to go for as a power source (avoiding charging circuitry & more dangerous chemistry, but at the expense of power capacity and reduced usability)?

To clarify some excellent points raised in the comments: the current draw is around 12mA at 3v, and the maximum cell thickness I can accommodate is around 7.5mm.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Coin cells are really only designed for a few mA of current draw.  How much does your circuit take?  Nobody's going to buy a product that eats $10 in 2032s every hour.

Comment: Yes, Lipo cells involve headaches, in shipping in particular. But a great number of devices use them, simply because there are no practical alternatives that are as good when you run the numbers.

Comment: If weight is not a dominant issue, consider using AAA or AA cell(s). If the consumer is concerned about environmental issues, they can get rechargeable versions and aftermarket rechargers for those. Another factor: permanently installed li-poly batteries have a finite operating life. Replaceable AAA or AA's overcome this.

Comment: Without any data how your device consumes power, impossible to tell. How much current/power it takes and what voltage range it supports? Is there an average and peak consumption?

Comment: You could build it with a holder for a standard Lithium cylindrical cell like an 18650 which the user could source themselves. Whatever is common in the 'vape' market.

Comment: EngTech1, Also keep in mind that button batteries (coin cells) are far too often left laying about for little children (babies) to put in their mouths and swallow. I think there are some 3-4 thousand cases a year in the US reported to the CDC. I don't know if that works out to a liability in court, or not. But I'd be pushing for AAAA, AAA, or AA batteries as a preference, if possible. And since you are willing to consider coin cells, it's certain that a AAAA will be fine enough. Lipo can't be a necessity if you think coin cells would work.

Comment: Thanks very much for your feedback all!
Power consumption is low- I'd estimate it draws no more than 12mA at 3v. AA/AAA/AAAA is a good idea - but unfortunately their diameters are too large for the current design, which can accommodate a maximum thickness of the cells of 7.5mm. AAAA could be an option at a push, but I worry these cells have lower availability?

Comment: COnsider not just nominal (average) current but also any surge (instantaneous) currents your device may have.   The internal impedance of coin cells is pretty high, so you'll loose voltage quick in there's any appreciable current draw at any time.  LiPo have nearly zero impedance, so will provide steady voltage under most any condition.

Comment: A standard camera battery pack might just do the trick for you....  Safe to transport, user can relatively easily get replacements, and very thin.   Check out something like https://www.batteryjunction.com/duracell-7k67bpk.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI6frsj7Gn-wIVD_nICh1b1w1SEAQYAiABEgLm0vD_BwE